# Android: Access method in an activity from another activity

Tags: android, methods, scope

My launch activity starts up another activity whose launch is set to single instance. In this 2nd activity, I have a public method. I then start up a 3rd activity and that activity needs to access the public method in the 2nd activity. I don't want to use `startActivity` and pass it  extras because I assume the `onCreate` will get called (or am I wrong?) and I need to avoid the 2nd activity from reinitializing itself.

When an activity is started using `startActivit`y, is it possible to gain access to the underlying class instance itself and simply call the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually came up with a simple solution. As a matter of fact you can access the underlying class of an activity. First, you create a class that is used to hold a public static reference to activity 2. When activity 2 is created, in its onCreate method you store "this" in the static reference. Activity 2 implements an interface with the methods that you want available to any other activity or object. The static reference you hold would be of a data type of this interface. When another activity wants to call a method in this activity, it simply accesses the public static reference and calls the method. This is no hack but is intrinsic to how Java operates and is totally legitimate.

Comment: I could be wrong, but that seems like you're going to cause a context leak by doing that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea. 
As I can understand method from second activity is actually not connected to particular activity while you want to call it from another one. So carry the method out to other (non-activity) class (maybe static method) and use it from both activities.

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly possible to gain access to activity object started using `startActivity` (without using some hacks). And frankly you shouldn't even trying to accomplish this.

One Activity component can cycle through several Activity java object while its alive. For example, when user rotates the screen, old object is discarded and new activity object is created. But this is still one Activity component.

From my experience, when you need to do things you described, there is something wrong with your architecture. You either should move part of activity's responsibilities to Service or to ContentProvider, or use Intents, etc. Its hard to recommend anything more specific without knowing more details.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to pass a reference via startActivity() however you can use some sort of shared memory to keep reference to your Activity. This is probably a bad design.  However passing an extra with your Intent will not cause onCreate, that is completely related to the lifecycle.