# Multiple request in AsyncTask Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I was having some problem with the AsyncTask in Android. So when the map on single tap, it will execute the method by passing an Event object as parameter in AsyncTask class to get the address based on coordinates X and Y:

```
mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {
        public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
            final Point point = mMapView.toMapPoint(x, y);
                eventModel.setEventX(String.valueOf(point.getX()));
                eventModel.setEventY(String.valueOf(point.getY()));
                 new MyAsyncTask(new MyAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                        public void onFinish() {
                             CreateEvent.createEventDialog(context, point.getX(),
                                    point.getY(), eventAddress);  //this will be called after the task finishes
                        }
                    }).execute(eventModel);         
            }
    });
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

**MyAsyncTask class**

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Event, Integer, Double> {
    public interface OnRoutineFinished{  //interface
        void onFinish();
    }
    private OnRoutineFinished mCallbacks;
    public MyAsyncTask(OnRoutineFinished callback){ //constructor with interface
        mCallbacks = callback;
    }

    public MyAsyncTask(){} //empty constructor to maintain compatibility

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(Event... params) {

        try {
            eventAddress = eventCtrl.getStreetAddressFromGeometry(eventModel.getEventX(), eventModel.getEventY());
            eventCtrl.retrieveEventJSON();
            if (params.length == 1) {
                eventCtrl.createEvent(params[0]);   
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        if(mCallbacks !=null)
            mCallbacks.onFinish(); //call interface on finish
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }
}
```

After user single tap on map, a dialogue box will pop out to ask for user input:

```
public static Event createEventDialog(final Context context,
        final double x, final double y, final String eventAddress) {
    AlertDialog.Builder AddDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    AddDialog.setTitle("Add Event");

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.create_event, null);
    txtEventName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventName);
    txtEventDesc = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventDesc);
    txtEventAddr = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtEventAddr);
    txtEventAddr.setText(capitalize(eventAddress));

    AddDialog.setView(dialogView);
    AddDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    addEventModel = new Event();
                    addEventModel = onConfirmAddEventClicked(context, x, y);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(addEventModel);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    AddDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AddDialog.show();

    return addEventModel;
}
```

And once the user click Okay, it will perform a DB insertion into MySQL via servlet. The onConfirmAddEventClicked() is basically getting all the user input and set value for each attribute and return as an Event object.

However, the problem that I was having now is even the user click on cancel, it still perform the DB insertion with only coordinate X and Y. I guess it's because the if statement inside the MyAsynctask takes in one parameter.

Is there any way to only execute DB insertion when the user click on Okay? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
            final Point point = mMapView.toMapPoint(x, y);
                eventModel.setEventX(String.valueOf(point.getX()));
                eventModel.setEventY(String.valueOf(point.getY()));
                 new MyAsyncTask().execute(eventModel);         
            }
    });
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}

protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        if(mCallbacks !=null)
            mCallbacks.onFinish(); //call interface on finish
         CreateEvent.createEventDialog(context, Double.parseDouble(eventModel.getEventX()),
                    Double.parseDouble(eventModel.getEventY()), eventAddress);
    }
```

With these codes, I am getting these error message:

```
11-11 21:41:29.457: D/dalvikvm(7062): GC_CONCURRENT freed 457K, 12% free 11022K/12423K, paused 74ms+124ms
11-11 21:41:34.074: D/dalvikvm(7062): GC_CONCURRENT freed 620K, 13% free 11021K/12551K, paused 56ms+237ms
11-11 21:41:37.589: D/dalvikvm(7062): GC_CONCURRENT freed 597K, 13% free 11018K/12615K, paused 29ms+7ms
11-11 21:41:39.441: D/AndroidRuntime(7062): Shutting down VM
11-11 21:41:39.441: W/dalvikvm(7062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c7e1f8)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:244)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.ENeighbourhoodActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ENeighbourhoodActivity.java:227)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.ENeighbourhoodActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ENeighbourhoodActivity.java:1)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
11-11 21:41:39.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 21:41:56.082: I/dalvikvm(7062): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-11 21:41:56.160: I/dalvikvm(7062): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this bug happened because there will be multiple `AsyncTasks` running when user typing repeatedly.

If possible , try to move your `dialog.dismiss();` from `setPositiveButton` to the `onPostExecute`.  Doing this will make sure the `dialog` will not close until the `AsyncTask` has finished its task, hence (i think) will get rid of the bug.

**UPDATE**

I just realized you execute the AsyncTask 2 times :

```
mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {
        public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
            final Point point = mMapView.toMapPoint(x, y);
                eventModel.setEventX(String.valueOf(point.getX()));
                eventModel.setEventY(String.valueOf(point.getY()));
                 new MyAsyncTask(new MyAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                        public void onFinish() {
                             CreateEvent.createEventDialog(context, point.getX(),
                                    point.getY(), eventAddress);  //this will be called after the task finishes
                        }
                    }).execute(eventModel);  //1st       
            }
    });
    //new MyAsyncTask().execute(); //2nd, try to comment this
}
```

If its still not working, see my comments and try to move the `createEventDialog` to the `onPostExecute` (no need to use `callback` and `onFInish` anymore)

Comment: But the problem now is like for example I single tap on map, it gets the coordinate X and Y and straight away execute the eventCtrl.createEvent instead of going into createEventDialog and execute only after user clicks okay. :(

Comment: @IWasSoLost please see my updated answer. Try to simplify your code by using only 1 AsyncTask

Comment: I need the asyncTask at the single tap to get the address and pass it to createEventDialog

Comment: Try to delete the onFinish, move the createEventDialog to the onPostExecute...see if theres any difference

Comment: Actually I need the onFinish so that the createDialogEvent will populate with the eventAddress. So you have any ideas?

Comment: @IWasSoLost Yes, onPostExecute doing the same thing..i think theres no use to use callback like you did in onPostExecute, since onPostExecute will only be called when you finished your onBackground :)

Comment: @IWasSoLost you execute your Async 2 times, please see my updated answer

Comment: I've updated my question already. Can you please help me take a look at the edited portion? Also if I commented out the second asynctask call, it affected some of my other function so I guess the problem is not there. I think it's because the 1st execution of AsyncTask take in one Event parameter. Then, inside the AsyncTask, I got a if statement for DB insertion which takes in one parameter as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64712/discussion-between-blaze-tama-and-i-was-so-lost).